# bison/yacc grammar disambiguation

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, yacc, bison, lalr

I have following bison grammar (as part of more complex grammar):

`expression:
    IDENTIFIER
    | CONST
    | LAMBDA match_block
;
match_block:
    pattern '=' expression
    | match_block '|' pattern '=' expression
;
pattern:
    IDENTIFIER
    | CONST
;`

which describe expressions containing identifiers, constants and lambda-functions with pattern matching, which looks like this:
`lambda 0 = 1
     | 1 = 2
     | x = x`
Problem is 1 shift/reduce conflict caused by ambiguity with nested matches, as in following example:

`lambda 0 = 1
     | x = lambda 1 = 2
                | y = 4`

Rule is that match block relate to closest function, as shown with indentation in example above.

My questions is - how can I rewrite this grammar to eliminate this ambiguity (without using %left %right yacc directives)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want the `|` to bind to the closest `LAMBDA`, that basically just means that you can only have a `LAMBDA` in the LAST `|` clause of a `match_block`:

```
non_lambda_expression:
    IDENTIFIER
    | CONST
;
expression:
    non_lambda_expression
    | LAMBDA match_block
;
non_lambda_match_block:
    pattern '=' non_lambda_expression
    | non_lambda_match_block '|' pattern '=' non_lambda_expression
;
match_block:
    pattern '=' expression
    | non_lambda_match_block '|' pattern '=' expression
;
pattern:
    IDENTIFIER
    | CONST
;
```

Basically, you split `expression` and `match_block` into two versions -- one that allows lambdas and one that does not -- and use the appropriate one in each spot to avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see one example of ambiguity elimination earlier in dragon book (for "dangling else"), but I was unable to do it with this grammar.

Comment: @SJ: this is essentially exactly the same pattern as with the dangling else -- the transform above is the same as what the Dragon Book describes, the only difference being that there may be multiple non-lambda match_blocks before the final lambda